# Test mobile web app in mobile device's browser using localhost

Tags: android, ios, node.js, html, mobile

I want to test a mobile web app on mobile device. I am currently developing my mobile web app. It is still on my local environment i.e. `localhost:8080`. Now I want to use same hostname and port to access this web app on my mobile device. I need this because my mobile web app is also using `HTML5 Accelerometer API`. I need to test if it is working. I can use google chrome dev tools to emulate responsiveness but I need to test it on real device.

**How can I test it on both Android and iPhone?**

**UPDATE**

Below is my nodejs server code

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('./dist'));

console.log('\n0.0.0.0:8000\n');

app.listen(8000, '0.0.0.0');
```

Comment: What are u using to host the file on your localhost? You might want to open this webserver for your local network, this way a phone connected to the same WIFI can reach your development machine via it's IP.

Comment: @rckoenes How could we achieve this?

Comment: Like I just asked, what are you using now to serve the web-pages on your local machine?

Comment: If both your computer (which is the host?) and your phone is on the same network, you should be able to navigate to the computers' IP and port 8080.

Comment: @rckoenes Currently I am using simple Nodejs server with grunt.

Comment: Read this: http://serverfault.com/questions/271824/node-js-is-not-accessible-from-external-ips-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

As Rosário said, you can connect to the same Wi-fi network as your computer and type in the computer's IP in your phones browser.
I don't know how experienced you are so make sure that you..

a) Use your computer's **local IP**. E.g. looking up your own IP on   [www.speedtest.net](http://www.speedtest.net/) won't help since this is your public IP.

b) Type in the port in your phones browser.
E.g. if your computer's IP is 192.168.0.10 then you need to type in http://192.168.0.10:8080 as the url in your browser.

Comment: Somehow this approach is not working. I get page not found(chrome's default message). Any other option.

Comment: To lookup your Ip address follow this url https://www.iplocation.net/find-private-ip-address

Answer (score 1):

Simply connect your mobile to the same Wi-fi network as your computer. And then Enter the Computer's IP on the mobile's browser.

Answer (score 1):

Android app "[KWS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.xeustechnologies.android.kws&hl=en)"

Its a good option to test webserver,

Comment: I am using iphone. I want to test on iphone only for now.